# ИСР жалуется на метод Void в C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuyCash
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Guy joe;
        Guy bob;
        int bank = 100;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            joe = new Guy();
            joe.Name = "Joe";
            joe.Cash = 50;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bank >= 10) {
                bank -= joe.ReceiveCash(10);
                UpdateForm();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("В банке нет денег");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bank += bob.GiveCash(5);
            UpdateForm();
        }
    }
    public void UpdateForm () {
        joesCashLabel.Text = joe.Name + "имеет $" + joe.Cash;
        bobsCashLabel.Text = bob.Name + "имеет $" + bob.Cash;
        bankCashLabel.Text = "В банке сейчас $" + bank;
        }   
}
```

Класс Guy работает у меня отдельно, без косяков.
Решил его привязать к Button и Label в интерфейсe.

За Label отвечает метод UpdateForm, который упорно жалуется на `void` и не хочет работать.
Ошибка вылезает ввиде: Expected class, delegate,enum,interface,or struct.
Проверил, вроде ошибок нету (но к сожалению не умею пользоваться откладчиком в полную меру). Программировать начал несколько дней назад. Помогите пожалуйста.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Переместите `UpdateForm` внутрь класса, у вас этот метод вывалился за пределы фигурных скобочек класса.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что он вызван банальной опечаткой и не будет полезен другим посетителям.

Comment: @Athari, с другой стороны, если сабж переименовать в C#: Expected class, delegate,enum,interface,or struct, то какому-то очередному новичку может и сэкономить время

Comment: @SanSYS Существует 100500 причин для этой ошибки. Можно что угодно засунуть там, где ожидается объявление типа. То, что в данном конкретном случае снаружи оказался метод — остальным ну никак не поможет.

Comment: А что такое ИСР, позвольте поинтересоваться?

Comment: @VladD, надо полагать, Интегрированная Среда Разработки :)

Comment: @VladD, IDE, по-нашему ;)

Answer (score 3):

Понял ошибку. Нужно было переставить метод UpdateForm выше.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuyCash
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Guy joe;
        Guy bob;
        int bank = 100;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            joe = new Guy();
            joe.Name = "Joe";
            joe.Cash = 50;
        }

        public void UpdateForm()
        {
            joesCashLabel.Text = joe.Name + "имеет $" + joe.Cash;
            bobsCashLabel.Text = bob.Name + "имеет $" + bob.Cash;
            bankCashLabel.Text = "В банке сейчас $" + bank;
        }   

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bank >= 10) {
                bank -= joe.ReceiveCash(10);
                UpdateForm();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("В банке нет денег");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bank += bob.GiveCash(5);
            UpdateForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эх, только хотел ответить :)

Comment: Всеравно спасибо большое! :)

Comment: @Klugge я бы предложил правку: нужно было двинуть метод UpdateForm не выше, а внутрь класса формы. А то, прочитав ответ можно подумать, что C# завязан на порядок объявления членов внутри класса...